# How do I display weeks in dates using JAVA Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

I was stuck trying to display the date from today and a date week from today.

ex) 2013.6.11 and 2013.6.17.

I am assuming getFromToDate plays big part here. So here are the codes.

Following is Controller page that seems relevant to it.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getFromToDate")
public void getFromToDate( 
        ModelMap model,
        @RequestParam int addMonth) throws Exception { 


    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Date currentDate = cal.getTime();

    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, addMonth);

    Date toDate = cal.getTime();

    String toDt = format.format(currentDate);

    String fromDt = format.format(toDate);

    if(addMonth > 0) {
        model.addAttribute("isMinus", false);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("isMinus", true);
    }

    model.addAttribute("fromDt", fromDt);

    model.addAttribute("toDt", toDt);
}
```

And follwing is .js page. ( I don't know if this page is relevant at all)

```
getFromToDate: function(searchBtnId, startDtId, endDtId, addMonth) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ctx+'/potcom/getFromToDate.json',
        type: 'post',
        data: { addMonth : addMonth },
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.fromDt != null && data.toDt != null) {
                if(data.isMinus) {
                    CommonUtil.$id(startDtId).val(data.fromDt);
                    CommonUtil.$id(endDtId).val(data.toDt);
                } else {
                    CommonUtil.$id(endDtId).val(data.fromDt);
                    CommonUtil.$id(startDtId).val(data.toDt);
                }
                CommonUtil.$id(searchBtnId).click();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(CommonUtil.Message.AJAX_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
},
```

Following is JSP page.

```
<td class="typeFD bgN">
<a href="" class="buttonA on" onclick="CommonUtil.getFromToDate('', 'startDt', 'endDt', 0); return false;">Daily</a>
<a href="" class="buttonA" onclick="CommonUtil.getFromToDate('', 'startDt', 'endDt', 1); return false;">Weekly</a>
<a href="" class="buttonA" onclick="CommonUtil.getFromToDate('', 'startDt', 'endDt', 1); return false;">Monthly</a>
</td>
```

When I execute the code above, only a month increases for Weekly.

20130611   20130611 for Daily
20130611   20130711 for Weekly
20130611   20130711 for Monthly

Using JAVA class, or whatever, how do I get the date a week from today as

20130611   20130617 for Weekly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

That will increment the calendar instance by 7 days

Comment: Exactly where do I put that code? Sorry I am new to JAVA/JSP
And I have to import Calendar.java in my JSP page. right?

Comment: Anywhere you like.. but I'd put it on `getFromToDate` method. Please review your java/jsp basics, otherwise this Q&A wouldn't be helpful for other people

Answer (score 0):

When you graduate to using Joda-Time or the java.time package in Java 8, look for the `plusWeeks` method.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime nextWeek = now.plusWeeks( 1 );
```